# How to make a Custom List View having thumbnail image of video link?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making an Android Media Player. I want to make a Custom List View which is having an image which has a thumbnail image of a video file. The thumbnail image should be displayed according to file name in this List View and should be displayed from a given link.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: In my opinion, it was kind of silly for the mods to close a ticket after it has been understood and answered to the satisfaction of the OP. Could this question have been phrased better? Sure, but I understood the OP, and isn't the point of this site to help people, not to penalise them? Sheesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be smart to use a custom Adapter for this purpose. You then override the getView method to build the layout. Here's an example from one of my projects that uses the ViewHolder design pattern and loads images asynchronously:

```
   package com.suterastudio.aca.gui.adapters;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.suterastudio.aca.R;
import com.suterastudio.aca.data.Tweet;
import com.suterastudio.aca.data.UserProgramme;
import com.suterastudio.aca.gui.images.LinkToBitmap;

public class TweetsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserProgramme> {
    private static List<Tweet> Tweets;

    public TweetsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<Tweet> tweets) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        Tweets = tweets;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Tweets.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Tweet thisTweet = Tweets.get(position);
        ViewHolder holder;
        // Inflate the view if it is null
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_tweets_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.profilePic = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.img_picture);
            holder.userName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_content);
            holder.position = position;
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Make sure we've got an actual event, here
        if (thisTweet != null) {
            // Additional null exception swaddling
            if (holder.profilePic != null && holder.userName != null
                    && holder.text != null) {
                try {
                    if (thisTweet.profile_image_url != null) {
                        new ThumbnailTask(position, holder, thisTweet)
                        .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);
                    }
                    if (thisTweet.from_user_name != null) {
                        holder.userName.setText(thisTweet.from_user_name);
                    }
                    if (thisTweet.text != null) {
                        holder.text.setText(thisTweet.text);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ThumbnailTask extends AsyncTask {
        private int mPosition;
        private ViewHolder mHolder;
        private Tweet mTweet;

        public ThumbnailTask(int position, ViewHolder holder, Tweet thisTweet) {
            mPosition = position;
            mHolder = holder;
            mTweet = thisTweet;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            if (mHolder.position == mPosition) {
                mHolder.profilePic.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) result);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            LinkToBitmap linkToBitmap = new LinkToBitmap(
                    mTweet.profile_image_url);
            Bitmap userIconBitmap = linkToBitmap.getRemoteImage();
            return userIconBitmap;
        }
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
        public TextView userName;
        public ImageView profilePic;
        public int position;
    }

}
```

Then, in your parent activity or fragment, simply attach the adapter. Something like this:

```
        LvMenu = (ListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.listViewTweets);
    TAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    LvMenu.setAdapter(TAdapter);
```

The use of adapters not only benefits performance; it streamlines the entire process of working with data-driven views, particularly ListViews.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a custom listview with a custom adapter.

```
    ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    CustomAdapter cus = new CustomAdapter(this);
    lv.setAdapter(cus);
```

CustomAdapter class

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
      public CustomAdapter(CustomListView customListView) {
    super(customListView, 0);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(customListView);  
    c=customListView;
}
public int getCount() {
    return 20;    //listview item count
}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

public long getItemId(int arg0) {
return arg0;
}

public View getView(final int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {  

            //Inflate a custom layout           

    return arg1;
}


    }
```

Working example @ http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Along with custom adapter you should use a ViewHolder for smooth scrolling and performance.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Here's a talk on listview by google developers

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&noredirect=1